# Rails bootstrap color depending on value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Project.status` can be `[1,2,3]`.
Is there a better way of defining the following logic (color depends on `status`), than doing it in the view?

```
- if project.status == '1'
  %td.bg-success= project.status
- elsif project.status == '2'
  %td.bg-warning= project.status
- else
  %td.bg-danger= project.status
```

Comment: I think can try this `statusColor = ["", "success", "warning", "danger"] and then statusColor[project.status]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def plan_label(plan)
        plan_span_generator(plan)
    end
    private
        def status_span_generator(status)
            case status
                when 'active'
                    content_tag(:span, status.titleize, class: 'badge badge-success')
                when 'inactive'
                    content_tag(:span, status.titleize, class: 'badge badge-secondary')
                when 'planned' 
                    content_tag(:span, I18n.t(status, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :event, :statuses]), class: 'badge badge-primary')
                when 'confirmed'
                    content_tag(:span, I18n.t(status, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :event, :statuses]), class: 'badge badge-success')
                when 'member_cancelled'
                    content_tag(:span, I18n.t(status, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :event, :statuses]), class: 'badge badge-danger')
                when 'client_cancelled'
                    content_tag(:span, I18n.t(status, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :event, :statuses]), class: 'badge badge-danger')
                when 'no_show'
                    content_tag(:span, I18n.t(status, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :event, :statuses]), class: 'badge badge-danger')
                when 'no_show_refunded'
                    content_tag(:span, I18n.t(status, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, :event, :statuses]), class: 'badge badge-success')
            end
        end
end
```

View:
Let's say `event.status == 'confirmed'`. Instead of `= event.status` in the view, I put `= status_label(event.status)` and the status is given a class like "badge badge-success".
 Works!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in following way. In your view:

```
- color_class = {'1': 'success', '2': 'warning'}
- default_class = 'bg_danger'

%td{class: (color_class[project.status] || default_class)}= project.status
```

I didn't get - what `else` means - is it any other status or just third. If any other - then `default_class` is suitable, else, just add another key-value to `color_class`

Also take a look at [ActiveRecord enums](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for statuses.

Answer (score 0):

```
color_code = {"1" => "success", "2" => "warning", "3" => "danger"}`
color_code["#{project.status}"]
```

Comment: do I put the first line in `project.rb` model? how to make the second line display in view?